# How do I replace a response file in Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Puppeteer seems to give one some room for optimization. I managed to filter out all resources that were not relevant for my scraping to boost the speed a little bit. Now I see, that Puppeteer is stuck on the main page html file for a very long time before being able to continue.
So my idea was to just download (as a beginning example) the index.html file, and make Puppeteer read it from my own storage. (In general it might not work for all files if the server dynamically distributes the files.)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:true,
        userDataDir: './my/path'
    });
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', request => {

        if(request.url()==='https://stackoverflow.com/'){

            request.respond({
                status: 200,
                contentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
                body:'<html>Test</html>'
            });
            //request.abort();
        }
    });

    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.jpg'});

    await browser.close();

})();
```

But I get the following error: `Error: Request is already handled!`
How do I do it before the request is handled?

Comment: This seems pretty unclear. First of all, there may be many other ways to optimize rather than this, so there's a potential [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) here. Secondly, we don't have a [mcve] here to reproduce the problem related to the error you mention, but correctness is an issue even though you haven't asked about it: if you're using the callback version of `fs.readFile`, then it returns undefined. You need to call `request.respond` in the callback where data is available, or (preferably) use promises.

Comment: If you mean by xy problem that I also look for other opportunities to optimize, then yes, I actually wanted to put an extra line asking with other optimization ideas. But that would split the question. I can try to make a minimal reproducible example, I thought the context was clear. I think I get what I got wrong about the fs.readFile. The data is only available in the function() oops.

Comment: It's asynchronous, so the data (`data`) is ready only after the callback runs. `console.log(fs.readFile())` and you'll see it returns undefined which is what you're setting your body to. I can't run this to see the "request is already handled" problem, so it's not reproducible. Other than the obvious `readFile` issue, there is nothing apparently wrong with the code here. It's generally hard to help with Puppeteer questions that don't provide the site. XY comes up all the time in efficiency/optimization questions. https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ might help explain why.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about, but yeah, people ask all sorts of stuff that makes it clear that they're heading down a completely wrong path but haven't told you what they're trying to accomplish or provide context, making it hard to steer them to the correct path (solving the _real_ problem X).

Comment: Rethinking about it, it looks like my problem X was not comprehending how fs.readFile works. But I had the same problem even replacing the body with ''. So it's not that, but that's just a oops not knowing the data was available in the callback, not in the return of the call.

Comment: Yeah, that's not problem X, that's a side problem you ran into solving Y. I'm not saying you _definitely_ have an XY problem, just that you might. It's possible that caching this index.html is a great win, and it's possible that it's a complete waste of time. Since I don't have the site, there's no way to know so I'm forced to trust your judgment that what you're asking about really is a worthwhile optimization. The biggest problem is that I can't help with the main issue, "Request is already handled" even if I wanted to since not enough info is here. So at least 3 problems 
 and we solved 1.